# ADOMD Connection Error

Tags: c#, ssas, adomd.net

I am receiving the following error from ADOMD while trying to connect to my SSAS Server.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in
>   Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.dll
>
> Additional information: Element 'return' was not found. Line 5,
>   position 2.

I can confirm the following:

My Connection String Is:

```
Data Source=<MyServer>;Catalog=<My SSAS DB>; UID=<MyDomain>\<MyDomainUser>;PWD=<MyPassword>;
```

I can confirm that my connection string is correct ( or at least the data I am using in the connection string above is correct).  If I change any part of the connection string to an incorrect value the ADOMDConnection will return "Cannot connect to server".  I have also looked at the audit logs on the server itself and confirm that I am successfully logging onto the server.  And the contrary, with incorrect credentials the server logs confirm a failed login.

I am trying to connect to SSAS 2014 Enterprise

The failed connection returns within a few seconds.  A few posts out on the internet suggest increasing the Connection Timeout property.  This does not seem to be my issue as I have increased it to 120 and its failing within 5.

I am using ADOMD 12.0  Runtime 2.0.50727

My domain user is a domain admin and has been added to an admin role in the SSAS.

Im not sure what else could be wrong or how to debug this or is this a known bug in ADOMD?

Any advice would greatly appreciated.

thanks!

Jason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens routinely when the version of the ADOMD client DLL is not a version that matches the target version of the server instance.  For example, Azure Analysis Services as of 09/13/2017 does not work with Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.dll version 13.  Only version 14 and above.

For reference, the ADOMD DLL for Azure Analysis Service is available in the link below:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/analysis-services/analysis-services-data-providers

Double check to make sure the client DLL is the exact version needed for the target server instance.  That solved this exact issue in my case.